# UICollectionView: scroll to item with offset

Tags: ios, uiscrollview, uicollectionview

`UICollectionView`: scroll to item with offset.

like the picture below:

[image]

Comment: Why don't you use a scrollview instead?

Comment: Why not calling `scrollToItemAtIndexPath:atScrollPosition:animated:`?